# Why does the display turn blank on a Thinkpad W541 when closing and opening the lid?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, suspend, thinkpad

I have a Thinkpad W541 which only shows a blank screen after opening the lid. The laptop doesn't go into suspend, everything is running while the lid is closed, and for a fraction of a second when opening the lid, I can see the cursor on a black screen, before the display goes blank.

This machine has a discrete Nvidia graphics card and a built-in GPU in the CPU. There is no BIOS option to simply disable the discrete graphics card.

This problem happens with the latest Ubuntu and the latest Debian.

I've tried to update the BIOS and embedded controller to the latest version and experiment with various acpi arguments to GRUB. I can't simply disable ACPI entirely, this renders the laptop unusable. However, less aggressive arguments have also been attempted, such as nolapic, noapic, I've also tried acpi_osi=\"!Windows 2013\" which was suggested here: https://gist.github.com/storrgie/d97f96f08b1a3685747ce71cd27ab1f3

I've also tried to switch between nouveau and the proprietary nvidia drivers and confirmed with lspci -v  that I'm now using nvidia instead of nouveau. Same problem, no difference at all.

I'm at a loss for how to deal with this. It is not just closing the lid which causes this problem. Whenever X wants to blank the screen (such as if it has been left unused for 10 minutes), it blanks the screen, and the screen never turns back on again.

If I hit the power button, ACPI initiates a shutdown, and then when the display changes back to the terminal to show the shutdown sequence, I again get a picture on the display.

Everything is working besides this, there's just some weird issue with the display drivers.